# \pagestyle{fancy} from fancyhdr seems to break \label-\ref if \label happens to be placed close to the upper edge of a page

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I am using `\label` inside a `\begin{theorem} ... \end{theorem}` environment. If it happens so that the theorem statement begins close to a natural page break AND `\pagestyle{fancy}` from `fancyhdr` is enabled, the `\label ... \ref` seems to malfunction for this particular theorem.

- ***Problem:*** Instead of pointing to the theorem environment, clicking on the link leads to the page just prior to the correct location.

Otherwise, everything seems to work fine, and I discovered this unintended effect by accident in a large document with several hundred `\label ... \ref` instances. Of course, the MWE is heavily reduced.

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{crossreftools}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter,style=plain,name=Theorem,refname={theorem, theorems},Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{theorem}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{fancy} %%%% <-- comment out to get working label-ref for 1.2
    
    \chapter{Test Chapter}
    
    \section{Test}
    
    \subsection{Testing}
    
    \onehalfspacing
    
    \newpage 
    s\\ 
    s\\
    s\\
    s\\
    s\\ 
    s\\
    s\\
    s\\
    
    s\\ 
    s\\
    s\\
    s\\
    \begin{theorem}
        \label{trm: test-label-to-theorem}
        s\\ 
        s\\
        s\\
        s\\
        s\\
        s\\
        s\\
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof} s\\ 
        s\\
        s\\
        s\\
        
        s\\ 
        s\\
    \end{proof}
    
    s%\\ %%%% <-- OR uncomment to get working label-ref for 1.2
    \begin{theorem}
        \label{trm: test-label-to-second-theorem}
        sd
    \end{theorem}
    \noindent Working~\ref{trm: test-label-to-theorem}, not working~\ref{trm: test-label-to-second-theorem}
\end{document}
```

Page three of output:
[image: Output of page three]

- ***To reproduce:*** The link for 1.1 works fine but 1.2 does not (links to page 2, not page 3 as intended). In my large original document, I checked about 30 other `\label-\ref` pairs, all working as intended.

In the `.aux`-file, the MWE as above writes, among other things,

> `\newlabel{trm: test-label-to-second-theorem}{{1.2}{3}{}{theorem.7}{}}`

which seems fine to a newbie, with {3} being the page number of the destination. But still, clicking 1.2 leads to page 2 instead.

- ***Toward reason for problem:*** You may comment out `fancyheader`, the problem disappears. Alternatively, you may change the layout a little bit, by adding a line before theorem 1.2 so that it is not that close to the top of the page. Then the problem also disappears.

***Question.*** How to fix this issue?

To apply the fix in my actual document, I cannot really remove `\pagestyle{fancy}`. Due to the large number of `\label ... \ref` pairs, it's not realistic to check manually which links to do not work properly and change things one-by-one, so some global solution is warranted. No errors or warnings are given besides the `Underfull \hbox`'es, neither for MWE or my original document.

I am running `pdfTeX`, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=`pdflatex` 2023.7.12); `LaTeX2e` <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>; newest `fancyhdr` 2022/11/09 v4.1; `hyperref` 2023-06-25 v7.01a.

---

Log file (with name of user account altered)

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.7.17)  17 JUL 2023 23:13
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./VeaOtsing.tex
(VeaOtsing.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/base\book.cls
Document Class: book 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/base\bk12.clo
File: bk12.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@chapter=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\c@figure=\count192
\c@table=\count193
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/setspace\setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2022/12/04 v6.7b set line spacing
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/amscls\amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\thm@style=\toks17
\thm@bodyfont=\toks18
\thm@headfont=\toks19
\thm@notefont=\toks20
\thm@headpunct=\toks21
\thm@preskip=\skip50
\thm@postskip=\skip51
\thm@headsep=\skip52
\dth@everypar=\toks22
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/thmtools\thmtools.sty
Package: thmtools 2023/05/04 v0.76
\thmt@toks=\toks23
\c@thmt@dummyctr=\count194

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/thmtools\thm-patch.sty
Package: thm-patch 2023/05/04 v0.76

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/thmtools\parseargs.sty
Package: parseargs 2023/05/04 v0.76
\@parsespec=\toks24
))
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/thmtools\thm-kv.sty
Package: thm-kv 2023/05/04 v0.76
Package thm-kv Info: Theorem names will be uppercased on input line 42.

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks25
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
)
Package thm-kv Info: kvsetkeys patch (v1.16 or later) on input line 158.
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/thmtools\thm-autoref.sty
Package: thm-autoref 2023/05/04 v0.76

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/thmtools\aliasctr.sty
Package: aliasctr 2023/05/04 v0.76
))
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/thmtools\thm-listof.sty
Package: thm-listof 2023/05/04 v0.76
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/thmtools\thm-restate.sty
Package: thm-restate 2023/05/04 v0.76
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/thmtools\thm-amsthm.sty
Package: thm-amsthm 2023/05/04 v0.76
\thmt@style@headstyle=\toks26
))
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2022/11/09 v4.1 Extensive control of page headers and footers

\f@nch@headwidth=\skip53
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip54
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip55
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip56
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip57
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip58
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip59
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip60
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip61
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2023-06-25 v7.01a Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2023-06-18 v2.52 Cross-referencing by name of section

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count195
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count196
)
\@linkdim=\dimen141
\Hy@linkcounter=\count197
\Hy@pagecounter=\count198

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2023-06-25 v7.01a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count199

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2023-06-25 v7.01a Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `hypertexnames' set `false' on input line 4050.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4167.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4172.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4175.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4182.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4187.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4434.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count266

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4772.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen142

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count267
\Field@Width=\dimen143
\Fld@charsize=\dimen144
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6051.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6056.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6059.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6066.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6071.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6081.

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count268
\c@Item=\count269
\c@Hfootnote=\count270
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2023-06-25 v7.01a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend pac
kage
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count271
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count272

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
85.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip62
)
\c@theorem=\count273

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count274
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
)
(VeaOtsing.aux)
\openout1 = `VeaOtsing.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 14.
 (VeaOtsing.out) (VeaOtsing.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `VeaOtsing.out'.


Chapter 1.
[1


{C:/Users/UserNameChanged/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 26--34

 []

Package hyperref Info: bookmark level for unknown theorem defaults to 0 on inpu
t line 40.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 41--48

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 49--53

 []

[2] [3] (VeaOtsing.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
 ***********
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `VeaOtsing.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 70E8118191D5A2EEAB659BE4B76F93F2;268.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8368 strings out of 475513
 132662 string characters out of 5771520
 1919238 words of memory out of 5000000
 29521 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 561190 words of font info for 46 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 75i,5n,79p,548b,538s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<C:/Users/UserNameChanged/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Users/R
asmus/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Users/UserNameChanged/MikTeX/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsl12.pfb><C:/Users/UserNameChanged/MikTeX/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmti12.pfb>
Output written on VeaOtsing.pdf (3 pages, 49180 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 60 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 11 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 25 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Did you read the warnings the package produces for your document? Not that it will solve the hyperlink issue.

Comment: Note this isn't a label/ref problem. The page reference is correct. It is the hyperref target which isn't. `\pageref{}` works fine in terms of the standard label/ref mechanism, for example. Just  the correctly printed `3` incorrectly links to 2.

Comment: @cfr There are no errors or warnings given besides `Underfull \hbox`es, neither for the MWE nor the original document.

Comment: I got a warning from `fancyhdr` with your MWE. Do you really not get a warning if you compile the code you posted? There could be version differences, but the package has given this kind of warning for years.

Comment: it is a bug in hyperref https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/294. I will think about it.

Comment: @cfr Indeed, there are no warnings besides the `underfull \hbox`'es. There is also an info text `Package hyperref Info: bookmark level for unknown theorem defaults to 0 on input line 40` which might be expected for the MWE. I added the log file to the question for your benefit. Thank you for your interest in the question!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the helpful information! I will keep my eyes open if and when the update or solution comes :).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The Github issue for this question [github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/294](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/294) has been closed. However, the referencing issue from OP persists (tested today with identical MWE, everything as up to date as possible). May I assume that fixing this issue would thus have required an impractical amount of effort, or would have been broken something else?

Comment: @LinearChristmas yes it is still broken. And it would be good if you could report that to the amsthm maintainer. They could easily add the target in the correct place and then hyperref could stop to mess around.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Appreciate the confirmation. Could ``thmtools`` also apply a fix? You know as well as I that ``amsthm`` has no de facto maintainer :). AMS are the authors and maintainers de jure but in truth the package is metastable, not mutable in foreseeable timescales.

Answer (score 1):

One can patch `amsthm`'s `\@thm` and `\@begintheorem`, based on the suggestion by @Ulrike Fischer at https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/332#issuecomment-2004158459, e.g., by replacing `\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}` in your MWE by the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@kernel@refstepcounter\refstepcounter
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\@thm{\refstepcounter}{\@kernel@refstepcounter}{}{}%
\xpatchcmd\@begintheorem{\thmhead{#1}}{\thmhead{\MakeLinkTarget{\@currentcounter}#1}}{}{}%
\makeatother
```

So it doesn't use hyperref for placing the target anchor at all.

Comment: I did two tests to try this out. Based on these results, your solution works. Thank you very much. For now, I would like leave this question open if you do not mind, as there is a new open github issue ([github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/336](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/336)) and perhaps some momentum to make changes to the underlying package ``amsthm``.